# Pyside retrieving a user input from QLineEdit

Tags: python, user-interface, pyside, qlineedit

I have a [QLineEdit](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QLineEdit.html) object which I use to retrieve the user input. I am doing [.text()](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QLineEdit.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QLineEdit.text) to get the text. However it returns me something like `<built-in method text of Pyside... object at..>`

I just want to get the string inside the Line Edit box. Just to be clear, I am also doing that when a button is pressed. So I write something and then press the button. 
I even tried using [selectAll()](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QLineEdit.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QLineEdit.selectAll), but it just gives me `None` every time.

```
targetText = self.targetTextBox.text()
print str(targetText)
```

Comment: It sounds like wherever you're calling ``text()`` in your actual code, you forgot the ``()``.

Answer (score 0):

I got the mistake I was doing. i was doing print str(targetText). I tried it with just print targetText and it worked.